# How can I transform a simple GUI java class into an applet?

Tags: java, swing, applet

I have this simple rock, scissors, paper java class, and I can't seem to convert it into an applet. I've researched the topic for over a week now, and I've tried several tutorials, etc. I just seem to be missing something; plus, applets are a totally new concept to me...

Here is my java code for TestClass.java that I wish to convert to an applet:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;

public class TestClass extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    public JLabel myLbl_P1 = new JLabel("enter Player 1 Name:");
    public JTextField myTxtTemp1 = new JTextField(4);
    public JLabel myLbl_P2 = new JLabel("enter Player 2 Name:");
    public JTextField myTxtTemp2 = new JTextField(4);
    public JButton myBtnPlay=new JButton("Play");
    public JLabel myLblResults = new JLabel("                         ");

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new TestClass();

    }
    TestClass() {
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        myBtnPlay.addActionListener(this);
        p.add(myLbl_P1);
        p.add(myTxtTemp1);
        p.add(myLbl_P2);
        p.add(myTxtTemp2);
        p.add(myBtnPlay);
        p.add(myLblResults);

        p.setLayout(new BoxLayout(p,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        p.add(myLbl_P1);
        p.add(myTxtTemp1);
        p.add(myLbl_P2);
        p.add(myTxtTemp2);
        p.add(myBtnPlay);
        p.add(myLblResults);

        this.getContentPane().add (p);
        this.setSize(400, 300);

    }

        //------------------------------------------------
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String winnerName, P1, P2, winnerStr, myStrResult;
                winnerName="";
                String Pl1=myTxtTemp1.getText();
                String Pl2=myTxtTemp2.getText();
                int winner;
                myStrResult="";

                if(Pl1.isEmpty() || Pl2.isEmpty()){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid Player Name","Error",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                }

                RPSPlayer player1 = new RPSPlayer(Pl1);
                RPSPlayer player2 = new RPSPlayer(Pl2);

                RockPaperScissorsGame x = new RockPaperScissorsGame(player1, player2);

                String[] result=x.rps(player1, player2);
                P1=result[0];
                P2=result[1];
                winnerStr=result[2];
                winner=Integer.valueOf(winnerStr).intValue();

                myStrResult=player1.getName()+" chose "+P1+"   ";
                myStrResult=myStrResult+player2.getName()+" chose "+P2+"   ";

                if(winner==0){
                    myStrResult=myStrResult+"   It was a Draw!";
                }
                else{
                    if(winner==1){
                        winnerName=player1.getName();
                    }
                    if(winner==2){
                        winnerName=player2.getName();
                    }
                    myStrResult=myStrResult+winnerName+" Won!";
                }
                //System.out.println(myStrResult);
                myLblResults.setText(myStrResult);

    }
}
```

I've tried changing:

```
public class TestClass extends JFrame implements ActionListener{   ***to***
public class TestClass extends JApplet implements ActionListener{

public static void main(String args[]) {   ***to***
void init() {

this.getContentPane().add (p);  ***to***
this.add (p);

this.setSize(400, 300);   ***to***
//this.setSize(400, 300);

this.setVisible(true);   ***to***
//this.setVisible(true);

this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);   ***to***
//this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

I'm not sure if I need to import anything else at the beginning either - maybe import java.applet.*; ???
Also, this is the html page I am trying to load the code with - I believe it to be correct:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <applet code=applet.class width="400" height="400">
    Your browser does not support the applet tag.
    </applet>
</body>
</html>
```

But, like I said I am completely new to this and I'm trying...
If someone could help show me the exact changes I need to make my original code into an applet, it would be greatly appreciated and would go a long way for my learning...

Comment: 1) The best way to deploy a Java desktop application (e.g. based on a `JFrame`) is using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info). JWS works from a link on a web page.  2) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Comment: Yes. It is for my professor. Actually he is all for JWS, but devoted part of a lecture and a lab assignment to converting GUI into an applet saying we should at least learn them, but he agrees with using JWS... Unfortunately, I recently had surgery this past week and fell behind trying to finish the semester...

Comment: *"a lab assignment to converting GUI into an applet saying we should at least learn them"*  Ask him if he has deployed an applet to a 'real world audience' (e.g. as an example for his students) within the last year.  There is a lot more to it now, than he might expect.  Applets *used to be* relatively easy to 'see in a browser'.  But those times are **long gone.**  Further, real world use of applets is shrinking as JS takes over many of the things previously done using applets (and typically does it better).

Answer (score 2):

To the core content, move it to a `JPanel`.  Use `JFrame` when you wan to display it in a window, use a `JApplet` when you want to display it as an applet

This is why it's generally discouraged to extend directly from top level containers (and place you core logic directly on them).  Separate your UI into panels which can be added to what ever container you want.

You should separate the management responsibility for these top level containers away from the rest of your UI, so you "isolate" components aren't trying to monitor "windows" when they might no exist, for example

It increases it's re-usability and decreases it's coupling.

## TestPane

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class TestPane extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    public JLabel myLbl_P1 = new JLabel("enter Player 1 Name:");
    public JTextField myTxtTemp1 = new JTextField(4);
    public JLabel myLbl_P2 = new JLabel("enter Player 2 Name:");
    public JTextField myTxtTemp2 = new JTextField(4);
    public JButton myBtnPlay = new JButton("Play");
    public JLabel myLblResults = new JLabel("                         ");

    TestPane() {
        myBtnPlay.addActionListener(this);
        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        add(myLbl_P1);
        add(myTxtTemp1);
        add(myLbl_P2);
        add(myTxtTemp2);
        add(myBtnPlay);
        add(myLblResults);
    }

    //------------------------------------------------
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String winnerName;
        String P1;
        String P2;
        String winnerStr;
        String myStrResult;
        winnerName = "";
        String Pl1 = myTxtTemp1.getText();
        String Pl2 = myTxtTemp2.getText();
        int winner;
        myStrResult = "";
        if (Pl1.isEmpty() || Pl2.isEmpty()) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Player Name", "Error", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        }
        RPSPlayer player1 = new RPSPlayer(Pl1);
        RPSPlayer player2 = new RPSPlayer(Pl2);

        RockPaperScissorsGame x = new RockPaperScissorsGame(player1, player2);

        String[] result = x.rps(player1, player2);
        P1 = result[0];
        P2 = result[1];
        winnerStr = result[2];
        winner = Integer.valueOf(winnerStr).intValue();

        myStrResult = player1.getName() + " chose " + P1 + "   ";
        myStrResult = myStrResult + player2.getName() + " chose " + P2 + "   ";

        if (winner == 0) {
            myStrResult = myStrResult + "   It was a Draw!";
        } else {
            if (winner == 1) {
                winnerName = player1.getName();
            }
            if (winner == 2) {
                winnerName = player2.getName();
            }
            myStrResult = myStrResult + winnerName + " Won!";
        }
        //System.out.println(myStrResult);
        myLblResults.setText(myStrResult);
    }

}
```

## TestApplet

```
import javax.swing.JApplet;

public class TestApplet extends JApplet {

    private TestPane testPane;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        testPane = new TestPane();
        add(testPane);
    }

}
```

This is the (auto generated) HTML file which was used to display the `TestApplet` in the applet viewer

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>Applet HTML Page</TITLE>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>

        <H3><HR WIDTH="100%">Applet HTML Page<HR WIDTH="100%"></H3>

        <P>
    <APPLET codebase="classes" code="test/TestApplet.class" width=350 height=200></APPLET>
</P>

<HR WIDTH="100%"><FONT SIZE=-1><I>Generated by NetBeans IDE</I></FONT>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

*nb* I had the files in the `test` package ;)

## TestFrame

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestFrame();    
    }

    public TestFrame() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Now, having said all that, I would strongly discourage you using applets, they live in their own little security sandbox which just increases the complexity of there development and would, instead, encourage you to have a look at [Java Web Start](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/)

Comment: Ok... I'm trying the TestPane with your HTML file...
I get the error:
ClassNotFoundException
test.TestApplet.class

I didn't realize Chrome wasn't offering java support...
I tried this in IE after updating java plug-in...

Comment: Make sure you place the class in the `test` package

Comment: Since missing over a week of classes, I'm not sure how to create the package for the applet either.
I put all the files into one folder: MyPackage
Then I put all the classes in that folder: RockPaperScissorsGame.class, RPSPlayer.class, TestClass.class, TestPane.class, and TestApplet.class.
Now I don't know what to do...